# Unable to get a long-lived Facebook Access Token with Server Side OAuth Fow

Tags: facebook, oauth, server-side, facebook-access-token

I am trying to get a long-lived Facebook Access Token so my java servlet app can monitor and retrieve messages and such for my users without reauthorizing every hour or two.

I am using the server side oauth flow and have everything working perfectly but am not able to get tokens that are good for more than a day.

The first user authorization call is:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=-----&client_secret=-----&scope=read_mailbox,manage_pages&force=true&state=-----&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A7101%2FeStarGlobal-eStarGlobal-context-root%2FOAuthCallback%3BJSESSIONID%3DvS9lP9JcF3B86zD99KVNGXzn2snKRl4V48lkJQD51cvXhpnLsT06%21-281618363%211342018780176%3FAuthSource%3D1%26AuthType%3D1%26EmployeeId%3D`97

The user authorizes my app and I receive the code on my callback URL and call for my access token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=-----&client_secret=-----&code=---code from above---&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A7101%2FeStarGlobal-eStarGlobal-context-root%2FOAuthCallback%3BJSESSIONID%3DvS9lP9JcF3B86zD99KVNGXzn2snKRl4V48lkJQD51cvXhpnLsT06%21-281618363%211342018780176%3FAuthSource%3D1%26AuthType%3D1%26EmployeeId%3D97
```

I receive a valid token that is good for about 6800 seconds and try to exchange it for a longer lived token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=-----&client_secret=-----&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=---token from above---
```

I get the same token with a slightly shorter expiration seconds.

I have enabled: Remove offline_access permission on my Facebook App page. I do not have an Enhanced Security Dialogs setting.

I changed the App Type from Web to Native/Desktop and that extends the expiration to about 89000 seconds or a day.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand. Have you removed your request for offline_access? This is simply the right permission to ask in your situation, as you will get non-expiring tokens.

Comment: That permission is deprecated and I am trying to use the new procedure to extend token life

Comment: Holy crap! Good to know! Glad I ran into this today!

Answer (score 1):

You say ' I do not have an Enhanced Security Dialogs setting.'

If that means you're not using the enhanced dialog - you need to to get the long-lived tokens.

If that means you don't have the option there to switch between enhanced and the old version, then it's probably not relevant - you should have the new one then

Comment: Sorry, I saw a relevant post but could not find that setting on the Facebook apps pages. It must have been the OAuth Dialog tab which looks like it is set to use the new Auth Dialog. I do have a checkmark for Authenticvated Referrals and nothing entered in the Permissions and QUery String(?code=) under Parameter.